# How can I draw IEEE-style graph in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

My advisor told me that the following graph is viewed as it is plotted in Excel and not seen as scientific.

[image]

its code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [width=7.5cm,xlabel={Number of data files},ylabel={Cost},grid=major,domain=1:35,xmin=0,xmax=35,ymin=172636,ymax=1810000,
            xtick={0,5,...,35},ytick={0,250000,...,1800000},legend pos=north west,samples=10,grid style=dashed]
            \addplot {100 + x * 50000}; \addlegendentry{$P1$};
            \addplot {100 + x * 55000}; \addlegendentry{$P2$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace*{-2mm}
    \caption{Costs of on different sizes.}
    \label{fig:gas_limit}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Instead can I draw a graph more looks like IEEE-style, where it does not view as plotted in Excel.

Example IEEE-style graph view could be as follows (where I find them from few IEEE papers). Please note that only its style it important for me:

- with color, [paper-reference](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8482108):

[image]

- without color, [paper-reference](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3330481):

[image]

Comment: You could change the font and font size for your pgfplots graph, and change the line colors, line styles and markers as well, these changes are relatively easy to make (you will be able to find most if not all of these modifications here on the site in other questions I think). However, I rather disagree with your advisor that the graph does not look scientific, many readers will be able to recognize this is pgfplots and not Excel. And even if it was Excel, as long as the graph is properly formatted it is just as scientific as any more fancy layout, in the end the contents [...]

Comment: [...] of the graph is what matters - I hope your advisor will agree on that and trust that other people will also appreciate the graph for what it contains and not for the colors that are used.

Comment: @Marijn I agree with you. I believe my advisor never used `pgfplots` or `tikzpicture` he couldn't recognize the difference -- It was hard to convience him that  I did not draw this in excel. // I am not sure whether each journal or conference has their unique graph format in latex, if there is he also wanted me to use their default graph format. But I was not able to find a default style for a IEEE journal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your graph as you like. Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{c1}{RGB}{0,113,188}
\definecolor{c2}{RGB}{217,82,24}
\begin{document}
\IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [width=10cm,height=7cm,xlabel={Number of data files},
            ylabel={Cost}, grid=major, domain=1:35, xmin=0, xmax=35,
            ymin=200000, ymax=1800000, xtick={0,5,...,35}, ytick={0,200000,...,1800000},
            xlabel style={black!70}, ylabel style={black!70},
            tick label style={black!70}, tick style={black!50},
            axis line style={black!50}, legend style={draw=black!50},
            legend pos=north west, samples=10, grid style=solid]
            \addplot[c1, very thick, dashed, mark=triangle*,mark size=3,mark options={c1, very thick, solid, fill=white}] {100 + x * 50000}; \addlegendentry{$P1$};
            \addplot[c2, very thick, dotted, mark=square*, mark size=3, mark options={c2, very thick, solid, fill=white}] {100 + x * 55000}; \addlegendentry{$P2$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace*{-2mm}
    \caption{Costs of on different sizes.}
    \label{fig:gas_limit}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I agree with [Marjin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn), default pgfplots is scientific enough.

Comment: Note that this does not fit into double column, is it possible to fit this into the double-column while shifting little bit left to remove emtpy space left side of the `Cost` label?

Comment: Sure, to fit IEEE double column format you should set `width=3.5in`.

Comment: Thanks! There is also ~10mm empty space on left hand side can it also be removed?

Comment: You can move y label to the top of the graph using option `every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north west)}, above=5mm},`.